# Is it possible to detect secondary devices paired via blue tooth to a device in adb

Tags: android, adb

Title says it all, really.  I am working on a python automated testing server that runs a few ADB commands to detect and deploy to android devices connected via usb.  I am wondering if one of those ish connected devices is paired with an android smart watch via Bluetooth, is there a way in adb to get that secondary device?

Comment: "if one of those devices is paired with an android smart watch via USB, is there a way in adb to get that secondary device?"

Do you perhaps mean paired via bluetooth?

Also, what hardware platform (bluetooth chipset) and bluetooth stack are we talking about?

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited my question

Comment: i am talking about via terminal from adb?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked in to this some more, and I don't think it is possible to do this from ADB.

You can call the Bluetooth Manager with `adb shell service call bluetooth_manager`

But the only transactions allowed

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/bluetooth/IBluetoothManager.java#IBluetoothManager.getBluetoothGatt%28%29

are

> TRANSACTION_registerAdapter =
>   (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 0);
>   TRANSACTION_unregisterAdapter =
>   (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 1);
>   TRANSACTION_registerStateChangeCallback =
>   (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 2);
>   TRANSACTION_unregisterStateChangeCallback =
>   (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 3); TRANSACTION_isEnabled
>   = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 4); TRANSACTION_enable = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 5); TRANSACTION_enableNoAutoConnect =
>   (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 6); TRANSACTION_disable =
>   (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 7);
>       TRANSACTION_getAddress = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 8); TRANSACTION_getName =
>   (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 9);

According to

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager.html

You need to getConnectedDevices and I cant find any way to do that.

However: Have a look in /data/misc/bluetooth and /data/misc/bluetoothd They should contain some xml that gets you the linkkey of paired devices and that might let you get the paired device as well.

I am working on proprietary devices that doesn't use those folders, so I cant check for myself.

Comment: I want to be clear, i am not trying to get connected bluetooth devices via java or the actual android device.. i am trying to use terminal adb commands.. i can get a list of android devices connected to my computer via usb using adb devices... what i want to do is then for each device see if they are paired with any secondary devices via blutooth, using terminal 'adb' commands

Comment: Something in the way of: adb shell service call bluetooth_manager